# Seemingly acceptable iptables rule blocking NIS (ypbind) from operating

Tags: iptables, nis

I am not an iptables expert.

I have a use case to block all outgoing traffic that does not destined for either 10.0.0.0/8 or 167.114.0.0/16.  I have two NIS servers (10.57.132.11, 10.57.132.40).  I generated the below iptables ruleset which I thought would work, but if I run *service iptables start*, I am unable to also get *ypbind* to load.  It times out on hitting the two NIS servers.  I see nothing in the logs other than a timeout.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Fri Jul 17 11:08:39 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [78622:10507056]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-I OUTPUT -d 10.57.132.11 -j ACCEPT
-I OUTPUT -d 10.57.132.40 -j ACCEPT
-I OUTPUT -d 167.114.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT 
-I OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT 
-P OUTPUT DROP

COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Jul 17 11:08:39 2015
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks, Jack.

UPDATE: To clarify, ypbind binds when iptables is off, but won't bind when I turn the above ruleset on.  Since it is only filtering OUTPUT and those rules seem correct, I don't understand the problem and I can't find anything useful in the logs.

Comment: The obvious one would be that portmapper isn't running?

Comment: Portmapper is running normally: rpcbind (pid  1342) is running...

Comment: Are your name servers within the ip-ranges specified?

Comment: Yes - all the NS are in that 10.57.132.0 network.

Comment: Time to put in a logging rule.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton - that was the hint I needed to solve it (see my answer below)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: iptables is really literal, don't forget localhost rules.

Okay! Got it.  Michael Hampton gave me the idea to use a logging rule (this was my first time).  So I did the following:

```
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  10.0.0.0/8           anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             167.114.0.0/16
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             nis1.example.com
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             nis2.example.com
LOGGING    all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LOGGING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix `IPTables-Dropped: '
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

From there, I started iptables and then attempted to restart ypbind and immediately saw this:

```
Jul 22 22:53:04 host1 ypbind[9844]: Unable to register (YPBINDPROG, YPBINDVERS, udp).
Jul 22 22:53:31 host1 kernel: IPTables-Dropped: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1476 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=18660 DPT=7606 WINDOW=2305 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Jul 22 22:53:50 host1 ypbind: NIS server for domain example is not responding.
Jul 22 22:54:01 host1 kernel: IPTables-Dropped: IN= OUT=lo SRC=127.0.0.1 DST=127.0.0.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1506 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=18660 DPT=7606 WINDOW=2305 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

OH NO! It's blocking localhost.  I added that to the output rule and got:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  10.0.0.0/8           anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  localhost            localhost
ACCEPT     all  --  localhost            localhost
ACCEPT     all  --  localhost            localhost
ACCEPT     all  --  localhost            localhost
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             167.114.0.0/16
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             nis1.example.com
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             nis2.example.com
LOGGING    all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain LOGGING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix `IPTables-Dropped: '
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

One more *ypbind* restart and

```
Jul 22 22:54:38 host1 ypbind: NIS domain: example, NIS server: nis1.example.com
```

There you have it!